# Does perchlorate(rocket fuel) and jet fuel make the salt and ground water near Cape Canaveral dangerous?

Tags: ocean, geochemistry, groundwater, pollution

I've gotten into paddle surfing and I'm looking for a place to live and surf.

I've been looking at an buying a condo in Cocoa Beach because of it’s proximity to Orlando and Cocoa’s decent but consistent surf break.

What concerns me is the perchlorate from all the rockets that launch from the Kennedy Space Center and also the jet fuel(kerosene) from Patrick Air Force Base.

Do you think that’s a legitimate health concern?
I'm curious because some of the properties seem "inexpensive".

EDIT:
I'm curious about the safety of surfing. 
My guess is it's fine, the ocean is massive; I don't swallow that much water surfing, but always some.

It does seem there are some contaminants in the water. It'd be a bummer to get Thyroid cancer or something like that. I linked to a book mentioning it below.

https://books.google.com/books?id=jlgBMowCT1YC&pg=PA9&lpg=PA9&dq=cocoa+beach+perchlorate&source=bl&ots=A7evkeQGt9&sig=oNhyFH8QCwDXARMJNDKbmtjI-8Y&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwj668bLjoLTAhUJRSYKHcgJDvQQ6AEIGjAA#v=onepage&q=cocoa%20beach%20perchlorate&f=false

Comment: Are you concerned with drinking tap water? or surfing in the ocean near the base? or what specifically?

Comment: aren't the ground stage fuels all LOX and kerosene? where is the perchlorate coming from?

Comment: I guess I'm concerned about both swimming and drinking the tape water in Cocoa. I know there there high levels of perchlorate in the early 2000's but I'm not sure how to research.

Comment: I don't know anything about how they power the rockets. I guess it depends.

Comment: I'm not sure this question is a good fit for this site. SE.Space_Exploration might be a better site for this question because it has more members who are more knowledgeable able rockets, rocket fuels & the products of combustion of such fuels.

Comment: I haven't run any of the numbers or done any research but I'm very skeptical that it's a genuine risk.   You probably breath in much more harmful stuff walking down the street by driving cars or living 10 blocks from a freeway than you get from space launches.